# Element is no longer valid selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm going through the months available in the combo and at each iteration it should take a text and then move on to the next month.

**The problem is that when executing the month change it appears this error:**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no
>   longer valid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)

```
//Select the month of June
Select combomes = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_Mes")));
combomes.selectByIndex(j);              

//Select the year 2016
Select comboano = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_Ano")));
comboano.selectByValue("2016");

//Click the browse button
driver.findElement(By.id("btn_Consultar")).click();

//Wait for the data to load on the page
WebDriverWait contas = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

contas.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.
id("dvPrincipal"))); 

//Get the dvPrincipal text

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("dvPrincipal")).getText());

//Now do the same for the next month: July / 2016.
//Until you arrive in December / 2016

}
```

[image]
**Retry, to locate the element after the DOM update.
I noticed that it does not change the name after updating the page, but unfortunately it is not found.**

```
//Select the combo that contains the months 
Select combomeses = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sel_Mes']")));

 //Lists the options of the combo that contains the months
List<WebElement> dd = combomeses.getOptions();

//Prints the number of combo options that contain the months
System.out.println(dd.size());

//Let's start with the month of June/2016
for (int j = 5; j < 12; j++) {
System.out.println(dd.get(j).getText());


//Select the month of June
Select combomes = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sel_Mes']")));
combomes.selectByIndex(j);              

//Select the year 2016
Select comboano = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_Ano")));
comboano.selectByValue("2016");

Thread.sleep(4000);

//Click the browse button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btn_Consultar']")).click();

Thread.sleep(10000);

//Get the dvPrincipal text
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("dvPrincipal")).getText());

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.navigate().refresh();

Thread.sleep(5000);

//Re-access the primary URL
driver.get(urlprincipal);   

//Re-access the URL from which the information will be extracted.
driver.get(prestacaodecontas);
}
```

Comment: where is the exception thrown? what line?

Comment: @MoeGhafari 
The error occurs after Click the browse button
driver.findElement(By.id("btn_Consultar")).click();

Comment: The code looks fine, my assumption is that you attempt to click the button while changes are happening to the page. easiest way to confirm is to add a sleep (temporarily) before your driver.findElement(By.id("btn_Consultar")).click(); if this solves the problem then i can propose a better wait condition

Comment: @MoeGhafari 
I have already placed before and after the click and I have already put implicit and explicit expectation too, even then the error occurs.

I have already put up a refresh on the page after the click, to see if it resolves and nothing.

Comment: @PauloRoberto, are you using the above mentioned code in loop ?

Comment: @NarendraRajput yes.

Comment: Implicit waits won't solve this problem. Combining Implicit and explicit waits is known to cause subtle bugs, so I'd suggest not using implicit waits. Explicit waits will only solve the problem if you're waiting for something indicating the changes are complete. As @MoeGhafari said, a sleep before the click will confirm you need to wait for changes on the page.

Comment: @paulo, that is why it  create problem because after your button click the dom get refreshed and it is still looking for your element . So again you need to locate the element inside loop too

Comment: @NarendraRajput 
Includes a second piece of code that I used in an attempt to find the element after the DOM update, the same error still occurs.

Comment: Can you share site url

Comment: @NarendraRajput 
Unfortunately I can not because it already has the logine data n password the proper url, I'm sorry;

Comment: Lets continue discussion on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140209/element-is-no-longer-valid-selenium-java